# Activity losses focus when service is started

Tags: android, android-service, android-lifecycle, android-menu

This is the current workflow, I currently have a onCreateOptionsMenu and onOptionsItemSelected implementation inside the activity.

The service which contains a layout (java class) and displayed along with the activity. Is started inside the onCreate of the activity.

But the issue is now the key events e.g. 
onKeyDown() , etc 
are all registered in the service class.

How can I get the focus back to the activity in order be able to capture the Key event defined in the activity.

I have tried using localBroadcastManager and fired it from inside the dispatchKey

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    switch (event.getKeyCode()) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
            Utils.broadcastKeyEvent(getContext(), event);
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
            Utils.broadcastKeyEvent(getContext(), event);
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:
            Utils.broadcastKeyEvent(getContext(), event);
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
            Utils.broadcastKeyEvent(getContext(), event);
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            MiscUtils.broadcastKeyEvent(getContext(), event);
            return true;

     }  
}
```

And I am receiving the keyEvent inside my activity, and am able to. openOptionsMenu and close it. But the main issue is once the menu is opened it doesn't reflect the keyEvents on the menu items. Although the keyEvent are received inside the receiver.

```
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        KeyEvent keyEvent = intent.getParcelableExtra(Constants.KEY_PRESSED_EVENT);
        Log.d(TAG, "Receiver got ketEventCode : " + keyEvent.getKeyCode());
        switch (keyEvent.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
                if (isMenuOpened)
                    openOptionsMenu();
                else
                    closeOptionsMenu();
                break;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                return true;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:                    
                return true;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:
                return true;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Would be nice to have some code examples to better understand what you are talking about. But from what you explained this seems really easy. Create a callback from your service class to the main Activity indicating that the event onKeyDown() was triggered

Comment: I had tried that by calling the dispatchKeyEvent from my layout class. But the issue is the keyEvent are not detected for the menuItems.

Comment: @portfoliobuilder I have added some code and more explanation. Please let me know if you have any more suggestions. Thanks